# What are these ethereum contracts with bytecode 0x and why are there so many of them?

Tags: etherscan

When digging through on-chain data I found a number of smart contracts with bytecode 0x. They seem to have failed creation but show up on etherscan with bytecode. I'm counting ~33k of these.

Any idea how are these being created? Is this a bug in the EVM? Here are 50 addresses where this is happening.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x20deb81c7d5d18028dded933be605505c938091a
https://etherscan.io/address/0x9fb62f66362c32d74c5b53229d4c22e1a24f5d52
https://etherscan.io/address/0x39782c2e98287f4c0e51f9e180cbe1456de6a1db
https://etherscan.io/address/0x5b8185bd10b593345f597e3e7caac42672b1c7fc
https://etherscan.io/address/0x9aeb3d1d552ce82e72f189b259eb36e5c908a12c
https://etherscan.io/address/0x341e998b7843ccf8f9eaaecbeae9bd3c6d7c588c
https://etherscan.io/address/0x424431739c7ddb993b911ccc2640f033d47b1a50
https://etherscan.io/address/0xcab65f4b0771aa81707a4455db752dff501d080d
https://etherscan.io/address/0xce515aa17fe6af10f1d5cb86bf9b1b5b8fac234d
https://etherscan.io/address/0x4872127cefbca9f654976ee405cfc9a8798f0d12
https://etherscan.io/address/0x9b6a174d23594423b05daa771192b83e8955cd58
https://etherscan.io/address/0x8bc415906f2ade7e21bb0c31a08adcee46381196
https://etherscan.io/address/0xdf8a6bcc68c1fefbcb97cc773d455b3ac4c08cc2
https://etherscan.io/address/0x07bb290e8255dff4321b309ef5034ebd2ce030cd
https://etherscan.io/address/0x0dc98635bf8aee484b4f14c0cd9f345d41e2b64e
https://etherscan.io/address/0xe2337e352f45caa1e02a0e73efab9e6ba6c8d922
https://etherscan.io/address/0x0cfb4fe57f6896771ad3077fff08e6aea68d55de
https://etherscan.io/address/0x70dec9b2e5bbf4aa46f451835118463aac5bc57d
https://etherscan.io/address/0x8e128d8f69ad9eef74c4bea53bee211b46d3ed12
https://etherscan.io/address/0x9193b74adb08dca4ce2d28cf3557d407a7376d0f
https://etherscan.io/address/0x66d3810cefd8d294a16d299ee4f3d2d055c8104b
https://etherscan.io/address/0xda01e4403fac105c1bdb367d74b7b21e670e3f13
https://etherscan.io/address/0xd14ed214e5575e63fdae13af57cdc8bf2c892daf
https://etherscan.io/address/0x615d1d1e7426d37b0f5b391e84baea52100f03cd
https://etherscan.io/address/0x1bc04584f83fc015e0c6ea26ca6bc35fc7570203
https://etherscan.io/address/0x02995472570dd1e2fc7e4e0e48c1753f94fee51b
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7d71a8213e49fe15ad69d47e2cf44119b7e8e3d9
https://etherscan.io/address/0xab59d7c754bd5aa990179ab8dcf5b01997f21faa
https://etherscan.io/address/0xa7123fe7256ed4edb4025ba8f0d902c88d218277
https://etherscan.io/address/0x04540dfa764af710f0f4c373e407a5aff15cbdb5
https://etherscan.io/address/0x3109c5d5571df1a085cdb934a965879a8a25c020
https://etherscan.io/address/0xd4fafbd76461416a55ef279394356e25b6237400
https://etherscan.io/address/0xa2ff79f05538cdedbe3eaa37446b54ad81a9b20a
https://etherscan.io/address/0x53705a412922b40e9a3295b697f29fc084939dbc
https://etherscan.io/address/0xf63972804ef22a4e86dfeb06bfb681c6bc2a4db5
https://etherscan.io/address/0xf8868d6099600cdec99a24b91adadea4875154b2
https://etherscan.io/address/0x8e601de08d7878429ea9a83544469f4da85aaa11
https://etherscan.io/address/0xbbf4e769cdb95c61ae448986174e560031a50c27
https://etherscan.io/address/0x106fe337f1f0c375f48fa2b7cdb602911c299e9a
https://etherscan.io/address/0xc5aeaf052732a1c2a663ccf19240010f138f78c0
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7da4fc9b273b09ee3ae276eae07d944c11b23ba7
https://etherscan.io/address/0xe2524cb9542e26a90abad220b22e85d7833696ec
https://etherscan.io/address/0x26dc58684b88abeb96451412b6aeb59ee521e3e6
https://etherscan.io/address/0xe53aaeaecbeaf0d31eef5cbfb4d14cdd7ded4dc1
https://etherscan.io/address/0x62c115d922b1b61e728644949425f97cbd709aa9
https://etherscan.io/address/0x1c27be806812460c9b2d0b12dfa03b8b5a1eb698
https://etherscan.io/address/0xa6e6b12a901326441b393489c0db4db56138720a
https://etherscan.io/address/0x827f7bab4db757063a525c511afdda42168b34f4
https://etherscan.io/address/0x50a0f5041b051c0943278eae08da9986c0d1e4cc
https://etherscan.io/address/0xd63a388134ce9f270cab4ac88e1fe1fbddeff050

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

That is occuring because during development, developers got somthing wrong.  Often a problem with the 'constructor' in a smart contract. They are arising because of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like etherscan displays the contract tab for contract creations, even if they fail to deploy. When the contract fails to deploy there's no code so etherscan shows 0x.

If you try to execute eth_getCode with an externally owned address or one where the contract has failed to deploy you'll get 0x back also.